# read data from analog input and sent it via serial port continuously

Tags: arduino

I have the code bellow to read data data from analog input and sent it via serial port. But, between two values the programm take a lot of time because of `println()`.

```
int x;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  x = 0;
}

void loop() {
  // Mesure la tension sur la broche A0
  x = analogRead(A0);

  // Transforme la mesure (nombre entier) en tension via un produit en croix
  //float tension = x * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.println(x);
}
```

I want the adc converts and sends data automatically to the serial port. Do you have an idea about how I can do that?

Comment: You're using one of the slowest baud rates available for serial.  Try using a faster one and serial will run faster.

Comment: In my case, I have have to increase the frequency of loop (make the arduino read data and send it to the buffer faster).

Comment: the baud rate it is the frequency with which the serial port read data from buffer, it is not my problem.

Comment: But you also call flush on each loop.  When you call flush it blocks until the entire send buffer is emptied.  The speed of that depends on the baud rate.  The baud rate IS your problem.  Try a higher speed and see that your loops go a lot faster.